# TFS Build and Powershell: how to acces predefined build variables

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I have issues with accessing build variables from powershell script for example I want to access Agent.BuildDirectory.
I tried:

```
$Build.SourcesDirectory
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

none works.

I know that I can use $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY but not all variables are available this way.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi @Darqer can you tell us which version of TFS you are using?

Comment: I use version 15.117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is TFS 2017 Update 3.  You should be able to do what you are trying to do.  Where are you trying to use the variables, as parameter in the build or actually inside a PowerShell script?  Those variable can be used as parameters and will be substituted at run time by the agent and passed to scripts, but if you are trying to access them inside a script like $(...) it will not work.  You do need to use $env:VARIABLE.  All variables in the variables section get converted to environment variables with their name at runtime. So for example if you are running an inline PowerShell like the image bellow, you *can* use $(..)
[image: inline script]

or if you want to pass parameters to the a PowerShell script you *can* also.

[image: passing parameters to script]

But from inside a script you cannot.

[image]

Comment: It would explain my issue, I tried to use variables inside ps1 script. Thank you very much for the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` not `$(Agent.SourcesDirectory)`. Check Agent variables from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables

**Update:**
Adding a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: True I made a mistake in my question, in my script there is $(Build.SourcesDirectory) but for $(Agent.BuildDirectory) I have the same effect, it does not work.

Comment: I use ps1 script file, not inline script. I was not aware that there are differences in data access between these methods. Thank you for your help :).